# Суммирование времени значений, записанных в тектовом формате

Tags: excel, excel-формулы

Есть столбец в текстовом формате, содержащий продолжительность события "мин:сек"

Для перевода в секунды я использую формулу

```
=ПСТР(A1;1;2)*60+ПСТР(A1;4;2)
```

Теперь мне необходимо подсчитать сумму всех этих столбцов (в секундах).

Понятно, что можно сделать дополнительный столбец с формулой, что указана выше и суммировать по ней, после чего скрыть этот столбец.

Но возможно ли сделать это формулой?

Как предварительно обработать каждую ячейку перед формулой СУММ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Время в Excel - дробная часть числа (целая - это сутки). Функция *ПСТР* - текстовая.

Если продолжительность события задана числом, данные не нужно дополнительно обрабатывать:

```
=СУММ(A1:A10)*86400
```

86400 = 24*60*60 (часы-минуты-секунды)

Формат ячейки с формулой - *Общий*

' ------------

Если в исходном диапазоне значения внесены текстом в формате *"ХХ:ХХ"*, где левая часть - минуты, правая - секунды:

```
=СУММПРОИЗВ(ЛЕВБ(0&A1:A10;3)*60+ПРАВБ(0&A1:A10;2))
```

Ноль к значениям добавлен для обхода ошибки при наличии в диапазоне пустых ячеек. Если все ячейки заполнены, *0&* можно не писать (при этом в функцию *ЛЕВБ* брать 2 символа текста).

Функция пользователя (*UDF*) для суммирования секунд в значениях, которые заданы текстовым форматом *"мм:сс"*:

```
Function SumTime(r As Range) As Long
Dim lSum As Long, i As Long
    For i = 1 To r.Rows.Count
        If r(i).Value <> "" Then
            lSum = lSum + 60 * Split(r(i), ":")(0) + Split(r(i), ":")(1)
        End If
    Next i

    SumTime = lSum
End Function
```

В ячейке листа формула:

```
=SumTime(A1:A10)
```

где *A1:A10* - сылка на диапазон данных.

Comment: Дело в том, что время в ячейках действительно в формате "Текстовый", т.к. при использовании стандартного типа "Время", данные при заполнении/отображении вели себя не так как нужно. В частности невозможно избавиться от обработки Excel'ем часов, когда нужны только минуты и секунды (первое введенное число всегда относится к часам, а не минутам как нужно; минуты не могут быть более 59)

Comment: Дополнил ответ вариантом для текстовых данных

Comment: То, что нужно. Огромное спасибо! Удивительно, Excel даже при вводе не показывает, что есть такие функции ЛЕВБ, ПРАВБ, но они есть :)

Comment: Да, в перечне их нет. Это те же *ЛЕВСИМВ, ПРАВСИМВ*, но из подкатегории работы с двухбайтовыми символами.